# Unable to see page library General settings in office 365 Enterprisewiki subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I have Sitecollection Administrator access. Created Enterprise WIki subsite.
Able to create New pages. But when i see the Page Library settings unable to see General settings

[image]

Please let me know any other Permission required in subsite level. Permissions are inherited from Site collection. Also i want delete the Workflow associated to the library.